# Orientation Issue with iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, ios8, xcode6

I have developed an `iPad` app for landscape orientation using `freeform` layout in one of

the `ViewControllers`.

It is working fine with `iOS 7`, but When I'm running the app using `Xcode 6`, the 
   controls in `xib` position varies.

I have Tried to modify `auto layout` check box, but no luck.
   Can any one help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't be using "FreeForm" to change the size of the views in interface builder. This **literally** means nothing for what happens at run time. You need to use size classes... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html and auto layout.

Comment: Ok I have removed this , It Is working fine now

Comment: Thanks a Lot Fogmeister

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

[self.window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Comment: No I M Using this line: self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

Comment: with the given code line ,My launching screen is not launching, It was just a black loading screen..

Comment: Try Above method and see if in interface builder you have use size classes - checked. If so turn off.

Comment: What is your actual issue.